# How to target array of dates in jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, css, datepicker

I am trying to trigger a change when specific dates are clicked in datepicker. I can't figure out why it isn't working. In this example, when I click on the first array date (Feb 7), nothing happens. When I click on the second (Feb 21), I get the correct alert `completed`. When I click anywhere else, I get both the `completed` and `open` alerts.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

var pastorder = ["2/7/2018", "2/21/2018"];

function eventDays(date) {
    var string = ( date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' + date.getFullYear();

    if (jQuery.inArray(string, pastorder) != -1){
        return [true, "pastorder"];
    } else {
        return [true, "open" ];
    } 

} 

jQuery('.week-picker').datepicker({
    onSelect: function (dateStr) {
        var date = new Date(dateStr);
        var string = (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' + date.getFullYear();

        if ($.inArray( string, pastorder )) { // In Pastorder array
            alert( "completed" );                           
        }
        if ($.inArray( string, pastorder ) == -1) { // Not in array
            alert( "open" );                            
        }
    },

    beforeShowDay: eventDays
});

});
```

Here is my first [codepen](https://codepen.io/aleks1217/pen/GQoVmm).

I also tried targeting the css without luck.

```
        onSelect: function (dateStr) {
        var date = new Date(dateStr);
        var string = (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' + date.getFullYear();

        if ($(this).hasClass( "pastorder")) {
            alert( "completed" );                           
        } 
        if ($(this).hasClass( "open")) {
            alert( "open" );                            
        }

    },
```

Here is my second [codepen](https://codepen.io/aleks1217/pen/pagMLq).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`$.inArray( )`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) searchs for a specified value within an array and return its index (or -1 if not found).

In your case, `$.inArray( string, pastorder)` is returning `0` when date is `2/7/2018` and `0` is falsy in Javascript, so the if block is not executing.

Update your if condition to `if ($.inArray( string, pastorder) > -1)`.

```
var pastorder = ["2/7/2018", "2/21/2018"];
jQuery('.week-picker').datepicker({
  onSelect: function (dateStr) {
    var date = new Date(dateStr);
    var string = (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' + date.getFullYear();
    if ($.inArray( string, pastorder) > -1) { // In Pastorder array
        alert( "completed" );                           
    }
    if ($.inArray( string, pastorder ) == -1) { // Not in array
        alert( "open" );                            
    }
   },
   beforeShowDay: eventDays
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm. I filled it out with the rest of my code and it's working perfectly.